# Is there a location in Draenor where there are tameable pets within seconds of a stable master?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Northrend the Dragonbone Hatchlings were known to be very good pet leveling battles because they respawn quickly and are located very close to a stable master to heal and resurrect your pets.  In Pandaria the same was for the Jungle Grubs in Krangasang Wilds.

Is there a location in Draenor where there are tameable pets within seconds of a stable master to not only powerlevel pets but also reach the 150 pet battles won in Draenor for the Level 3 Pet Menagerie?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to stay in Draenor?  The pets there are 23-25 like most of Pandaria, and the lack of flying makes moving around more of a hassle.  Pandaria master tamer dailies and pets in the Vale are probably still the best bet for power-leveling pets.  You can also do the Draenor tamers for the new reward token, but there are not very many of them.

Comment: Convenience of travel - it's a lot easier to just fly to a destination and start pet battling than fly, portal, fly. (Fly as in flight path).

Comment: I don't see why Dragonbone Hatchlings are any less effective for leveling pets, especially when using Onyxian Whelpling as your main pet. If you are concerned about travel time, use a mage alt for easy ports to Dalaran combined with a short flight at 280%.

Comment: I'm not sure levelling a Mage alt to 71 is a compelling argument in favour of something being convenient. :P  Anyway, added a second reason.

Answer (score 1):

The best (and only) place I've located is outside Pinchwhistle Gearworks.  There is a faction-agnostic stable master inside Pinchwhistle, and plenty of pets (a combination of beast, critter, flying and the occasional aquatic) scattered up and down outside the land entrance of it.